# meaning of setUseAdjustedValues(True) om pyalgotrade

Tags: python-2.7, pyalgotrade

Here is an example of SMA cross strategy, what is the reason we use `self.setUseAdjustedValues(True)`
and how does it works?

```
from pyalgotrade import strategy
from pyalgotrade.technical import ma
from pyalgotrade.technical import cross


class SMACrossOver(strategy.BacktestingStrategy):
    def __init__(self, feed, instrument, smaPeriod):
        strategy.BacktestingStrategy.__init__(self, feed)
        self.__instrument = instrument
        self.__position = None
        # We'll use adjusted close values instead of regular close values.
        self.setUseAdjustedValues(True)
        self.__prices = feed[instrument].getPriceDataSeries()
        self.__sma = ma.SMA(self.__prices, smaPeriod)

    def getSMA(self):
        return self.__sma

    def onEnterCanceled(self, position):
        self.__position = None

    def onExitOk(self, position):
        self.__position = None

    def onExitCanceled(self, position):
        # If the exit was canceled, re-submit it.
        self.__position.exitMarket()

    def onBars(self, bars):
        # If a position was not opened, check if we should enter a long position.
        if self.__position is None:
            if cross.cross_above(self.__prices, self.__sma) > 0:
                shares = int(self.getBroker().getCash() * 0.9 / bars[self.__instrument].getPrice())
                # Enter a buy market order. The order is good till canceled.
                self.__position = self.enterLong(self.__instrument, shares, True)
        # Check if we have to exit the position.
        elif not self.__position.exitActive() and cross.cross_below(self.__prices, self.__sma) > 0:
            self.__position.exitMarket()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use regular close values, instead of adjusted ones, your strategy may react to price changes that are actually the result of a stock split and not a price change due to regular trading activity.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood and trying to simplify it, suppose a share of price is 100.

-> next day share splits in 1:2 means 2 shares of 50 each. this price change are not due to trading activities, there is not trade involve for lower this price. So setUseAdjustedValues(True) handle this situation.